# Question about c++ memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

Instead of

```
int *i = new int;
...
delete i;
```

could I just do this?

```
int i;
...
delete &i;
```

Comment: The address of i won't be known to the underlying platform memory allocator as it is on the stack.

Comment: It is almost never necessary or desirable to allocate a variable of built-in type on the heap using new.

Comment: Read up about stack and heap to understand why that won't work.

Answer (score 10):

You don't want to do that. The int declared on the stack will be cleaned up when the code goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
int i;

i = 5 + 5;
```

Comment: What is with the downvote here? OP clearly doesn't get heap-based allocation vs stack variables.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a variable on the stack, its destructor will be called and the memory reclaimed when it goes out of scope.

If you allocate space from a heap, you have to free that space explicitly.

You cannot mix these two strategies.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

Long answer:

```
int i;
```

declares a int on the stack.  This int will be removed when the int falls out of scope.

```
int *i = new int;
```

declares an int pointer on the stack, then creates a int on the heap (the new) and assigns the address of the heap value to the stack value.  Again, the int pointer is removed when it falls out of scope, but the heap value sticks around unless it's deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You should only dynamically allocate variables if you **need** them on the *heap*.

A common misconception (or habit) from people who program in other languages, such as java, is to use the `new` operator to create every variable.  This is not necessary and may cause fragmentation in your code.

In C++, for small variables, just declare them:
  `int i;`
instead of:
  `int * i = new int;`
By not declaring them using the `new` operator, you are allowing the compiler to automatically dispose of them when necessary (a.k.a. when leaving scope).  This saves the burden of allocation and deallocation from the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  In fact, NO!  You can only use `delete` to free memory that was allocated by `new`.  If you call `delete` on a pointer to a local variable, or a pointer to memory allocated by `malloc()`, your program will likely crash.

Also, be sure to understand the difference between `delete` and `delete []`.

Not to mention that there is no need to delete a local variable.  It is allocated on the stack, and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope (e. g. when the function returns).

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
int i;
```

After the closing brace for the code block the integer is declared in, it'll be removed from the stack anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate it on the stack, do this:

```
int i;
i=5;
```

The int will be remove when the stack will go out of scope (when you quit the function for instance).

If you want to allocate it on the heap, do this:

```
int* i = new int; 
*i = 5;
delete i;
```

This will create you a pointer to a int on the heap. Delete it when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: No. Don't do memory management like that. There is no exception safety. All pointers (dynamically allocated) should be wrapped in a smart pointer (there are several available in the standard library). In real production code there should hardly ever be any delete's in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this

```
int i; 
...
delete &i;
```

But if You really must allocate an int on the heap and You absolutely want your variable to look like a normal int variable, You could try this:

```
int &i = *(new int); 
...
delete &i;
```

Comment: But of course this last example would neither be exception-safe or especially time efficient, and probably confuse everyone, even the original coder.

Comment: Could You elaborate on the lack of exception safety please? Do you suggest the pointer is safer?

Comment: It means if an exception is thrown or the function is otherwise left early without a chance to delete, you've leaked memory. Pointers should be put in automatically (stack) allocated variables that will delete in their destructor (like `auto_ptr` or Boost `shared_ptr`) so you don't have to worry about memory management.